# SAS grab previous observation for comparison

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a SAS dataset similar to:

```
Joe
Joe
John
Bill
Bill
Bill
Bill
Joanne
Joanne
Fred
Fred
Fred
Ted
```

What I am trying to do is make it into a new dataset that has each entry only once, with an added variable that stores the "streak" of that variable. For example, the set would look like:

```
Joe     2
Bill    4
Joanne  2
Fred    3
Ted     1
```

So far I've created the first data set but am stuck on how to do the second. My **idea** is to create a variable in the data step that holds the value of the last observation for comparison, but I can't figure out how to do that, or then how I'd turn it into the second data set.

I'm not sure if returning to the previous observation is even possible in SAS, maybe this is a problem for a `proc sql`, but then I need a new `data set` not a table.

Answer (score 4):

If the name will only occur once, i.e. you can't have a streak thats bill, bill, joe, joe, bill, bill then use proc freq:

```
proc freq data=have;
table name/out=want;
run;
```

Otherwise use the notsorted option with a counter.

```
data want;
set have;

*BY tells sas my data has groups according to the "Name" variable , 
with the notsorted meaning that it isn't an alphabetical or numerical order
basically, whenever the Name changes its a new group;
by name notsorted;

*Keep the value across the different rows rather than reset;
retain counter;

*if this is the first of a group then set the counter to 1;
if first.name then counter=1;
*If this isn't the first name in the group then increment the counter,
retain means its kept the value from previous row;
else counter+1;

*If this is the last of the "Name" group then output the observation;
if last.name then output;
run;
```

Comment: @Kavan FYI, if this is a homework/classwork question, you should probably note some information about that in the question.  SAS has some amazing elements that mean we can give you some pretty complicated answers, so letting us know the context helps us give a useful answer and perhaps reminds answerers to give more complete answers (we should always have that information in the answer, but sometimes we forget.)

Comment: Arrays would be the very wrong way to go here. In most other languages it would make sense, but since SAS processes data row by row, an array is usually used to process a single row of data, not a column of data.